# How to grab variables from a data log

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'll preface this question by stating that I am very new to Javascript and programming as a whole as I'm a current first year student. I am attempting to create an app which makes use of data given to me by an API. However, this API only  returns the data as one whole String with different subsections.

This is how the return looks when logged:

```
User {
  id: 'redacted',
  username: 'Despacito II',
  platform: 'PC',
  url: 'https://fortnitetracker.com/profile/pc/Despacito II',
  stats:
   { solo:
      Mode {
        score: 101032,
        kd: 0.35,
        matches: 916,
        kills: 324,
        kills_per_match: 0.35,
        score_per_match: 110.3,
        wins: 1,
        top_3: 1,
        top_5: 2,
        top_6: 4,
        top_12: 8,
        top_25: 231 },
     duo:
      Mode {
        score: 29650,
        kd: 0.47,
        matches: 198,
        kills: 92,
        kills_per_match: 0.46,
        score_per_match: 149.75,
        wins: 2,
        top_3: 2,
        top_5: 23,
        top_6: 27,
        top_12: 104,
        top_25: 158 },
     squad:
      Mode {
        score: 166404,
        kd: 0.42,
        matches: 795,
        kills: 323,
        kills_per_match: 0.41,
        score_per_match: 209.31,
        wins: 31,
        top_3: 120,
        top_5: 151,
        top_6: 488,
        top_12: 790,
        top_25: 1580 },
     current_solo:
      Mode {
        score: 16660,
        kd: 0.62,
        matches: 128,
        kills: 80,
        kills_per_match: 0.62,
        score_per_match: 130.16,
        wins: 0,
        top_3: 0,
        top_5: 0,
        top_6: 0,
        top_12: 0,
        top_25: 34 },
     current_duo:
      Mode {
        score: 11907,
        kd: 0.78,
        matches: 60,
        kills: 45,
        kills_per_match: 0.75,
        score_per_match: 198.45,
        wins: 2,
        top_3: 2,
        top_5: 12,
        top_6: 16,
        top_12: 55,
        top_25: 87 },
     current_squad:
      Mode {
        score: 24822,
        kd: 0.56,
        matches: 130,
        kills: 70,
        kills_per_match: 0.54,
        score_per_match: 190.94,
        wins: 4,
        top_3: 19,
        top_5: 23,
        top_6: 69,
        top_12: 115,
        top_25: 230 },
     lifetime:
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object] ] } }
```

I was wondering how I could take this return and retrieve variables from it. For example, have a new variable called 'kdSolo' and have it equal 0.35 as per the APIs return?

I'd also love to know if there is a specific term for this and what it is for future reference and research. Sorry again for the noobie question.

Comment: It would be easier if you provide the actual JSON returned from the API.

Comment: User.stats.solo.Mode.kd ?

Comment: @Akrion biggest mind blown moment, I believe what I put in is the JSON returned from the API. Didn't realise APIs sent JSONs. I'll search for my problem with that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to `walk` the current object tree then you could simply do:

```
var kdSolo = User.stats.solo.Mode.kd
// kdSolo will now be 0.35
```

The reason I asked about the JSON is because what you have above is not a valid JSON object.

Comment: What I've done is assigned the API call to an object called stats "stats = fortnite.user(name, 'pc');" but when I try to call "var kdSolo = stats.User.stats.solo.Mode.kd;" I get given this error "var kdSolo = stats.User.stats.solo.Mode.kd;
                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'stats' of undefined"

Comment: What are the contents of the `stats` which you assigned to `fortnite.user(name, 'pc');`?

Comment: Other way round. The contents of 'stats' are 'fortnite.user(name, 'pc'); ... This is so, I assume, I could then do stats.User.stats.solo.Mode.kd 

The contents of stats would thus look like the example I provided above.

Comment: What do you get in the console if you do `console.log(JSON.stringify(stats))? Right after your `stats = fortnite.user(name, 'pc');`

Comment: I get the exact same output that was given in the OP